# service load fails through createprocess?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a windows service.

**I can install it through cmd with "`c:\serviceName -install"`**

when I do `createProcess` and pass command line `-install` **it does not appear in the `Service Control manager`**. The createProcess returns non-zero value

"GetExitCodeProcess" gives `0`.

Following is a line from the code:

CreateProcess(Process,pCmdLine,NULL,NULL,FALSE,DETACHED_PROCESS,NULL,NULL,&stStartupInfo,pProcessInfo);

Variable name are fairly self-explained.

Please comment.